# when the image load event with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, image, events

i want to make one of the images disappear (opacity 0 ) but when the images completely load 
here is the code :

```
var imges = document.getElementsByTagName('img');


imges[0].style.opacity=0;
```

how to write the event of when the images load  completely then do this  ?

of course with vanilla javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically append to it the dom to ensure the event listener is on there before it is parsed by the browser like below.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
   this.style.opacity = 0;
}
img.src = "The url or path to your image.";
```

Comment: my onload function never gets called. Src is valid.